# How to add newline to output using putchar

Tags: c

[Edited/corrected] I have a task to print all letters in lower case using putchar, so after writing my code I found out that a newline was not included.
But it wrote each character on a separate line in my terminal.
How can I make all the letters be on one line?

I've tried:

```c
putchar(ch);
putchar('\n');
```

This is the complete code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                     
/**                                                                                                                                     
 * main - starting my program                                                                                                           
 * int ch - introduce ch                                                                                                                
 * for = for every ch <= print body                                                                                                     
 *                                                                                                                                      
 * Return: always 0                                                                                                                     
 */                                                                                                                                     
int main(void)                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                       
    int ch;                                                                                                                         
    for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                               
        putchar (ch);                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        putchar ('\n');
    }                                                                                                                               
    return (0);
}
```

I want my result to be in this form

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Not:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
...
```

Comment: Most probably you need to print the newline only once after the loop.

Comment: What you have shown us is valid code, must be smth else.

Comment: @manny, Why is `putchar ('\n');` inside the `for` loop rather than after it?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Reinstate That was why i was getting it wrong....I've fixed it now.Thanks

Comment: Don't edit the question with the solution — it makes nonsense of your question.  I've undone the change that moved `putchar('\n')` from inside the loop to outside the loop so that is back inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This will fix it:

```c
int main(void)                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                       
    int ch;                                                                                                                         
    for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                               
        putchar (ch);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }    
    putchar ('\n');     
    return (0);
}
```

Newline does exactly what it sounds like... it creates a new line. That's why every character is on a new line in your code. You want to print it once, after printing the whole alphabet, not print it after each character.

Comment: Thanks it worked..i placed the newline in the main body